# remove explicit unix file permissions

Tags: linux, file, unix, permissions, file-permissions

after I've accidentally run

```
setfacl -R -m u:someuser:--- /*
```

every new user I create has the same nonsense explicit '---' on every single file on the system, which make it quite unpleasant situation:

on everything (/bin/bash and so on included):

```
root@mymachine:/everything/whatever# getfacl something
# file: something
# owner: me
# group: me
user::rwx
user:newlycreateduser:---
group::r-x
mask::r-x
other::r-x
```

Can you please point me to some solution, how to create new users with default (viable) set of permissions? Or to get rid of this behaviour?

adduser / useradd used with various settings / primary groups 
(this is debian, but I guess this is a general unix question)
played with it all day yesterday... with no effect.

Thanks!

Comment: You can try `setfacl --restore=/*`. I am not sure.

Comment: @Karthikeyan.R.S Unfortunately `setfacl --restore=backupfile` would be fine only if I had previously created a backup via `getfacl something > backupfile`, which I hadn't.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that bad: when I tried to create new users, I everytime deleted the previous one so the new one probably got the same uid as the previous. Permissions on these files therefore persisted. Now when I created a new user without deleting the previous (so it got previously unused, new uid) it GOT THE PERMISSIONS AS IT SHOULD.

I didn't expect this behaviour (and still can't believe it).